# TXT records and Exchange 2010 Federation

Tags: exchange-2010

I am confused as to how many TXT records I require for Exchange 2010 Federation.

If my organisation uses @abc.com as the primary SMTP address and @xyz.com as an alias, do I create the following TXT records using individual proof values?

1) exchangedelegation.abc.com

2) abc.com

3) xyz.com

Do I need the exchangedelegation.abc.com TXT record at all?
The newer Microsoft documentation does not seem to mention this.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Huh? Adding aliases is as simple as adding the domain to Accepted Domains in Exchange and adding the domain to your Email Address Policy. What Federation are you referring to? Federation isn't required for adding an additional authoritative domain to Exchange.

Comment: Like @joeqwerty said..are you referring to adding the alias or do you already have the alias and you want to federate your company's abc and xyz email domains with a 3rd party for free/busy?  http://www.expta.com/2011/07/how-to-configure-exchange-2010-sp1.html will help if that's the case.  However, Exchange 2010 is going end of support in the next 6 months and you won't get a lot of help here due to this.

Comment: I was referring to MFG (Microsoft Federation Gateway) for sharing free/busy data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that for Microsoft Federation Gateway, subdomain exchangedelegation.abc.com is only required for Exchange 2010 SP1.  SP3 does not need this subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

If @xyz.com is only for additional email address, you didn’t need TXT record for @xyz.com.
The domain you select will be used to configure the OrgID for the federation trust.

federated domain: An accepted authoritative domain that's added to the organization identifier (OrgID) for an Exchange organization.

Make a note of the federated domain proof that's generated for the primary shared domain. You'll use this string to create a TXT record on your public DNS server.